# element positioning html css

Tags: html, css

when you hover over the image you get a caption, but the h1 and p are on the same position, the p element does not come under the h1 element.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
        <section role="main" class="container">
        <ol class="thumb-grid group">
            <li><img src="img.jpg" alt="img" />
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div><!-- einde caption-text -->
            </div><!-- einde caption -->
            </li>
```

CSS

```
.thumb-grid .caption{
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.thumb-grid li:hover .caption{
opacity: 1;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 5;
position: absolute;
}

.thumb-grid .caption-text{
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: left;
padding-top:8%;
padding-left:8%;
}
.thumb-grid .caption-text h1{
font-size: 1em;
}
.thumb-grid .caption-text p{
font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wfRA6/
It works??

Comment: with me it doesn't work, I don't understand why...

Comment: Which browser you use to test the code??I test it using G.Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine for me on all my browsers, you could try putting:

```
position:relative;
```

into your .thumb-grid .caption-text p{ this should auto align it below your html.
I hope this answers your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't understand where and what's your problem, because i see the P under de H1

Here u can see the test

http://jsfiddle.net/mp98n/1/

I use your code

```
<section role="main" class="container">
    <ol class="thumb-grid group">
        <li><img src="img.jpg" alt="img" />
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-text">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div><!-- einde caption-text -->
        </div><!-- einde caption -->
        </li>
```

I hope this help